# Run PHP when Input is changed

Tags: php

I was wondering if there was a way of running PHP when an input is changed, the input is question is:

```
<input id="custom_file_upload" type="file" name="Filedata" />
```

I was thinking prehaps using some jQuery or AJAX to run an external file when changed?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/change/

mixed with

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Great example of this idea can be seen in some examples here: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Usernames and emails are validated against a script, to make sure they do not already exist in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, AJAX will be the way to go. Using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$("#custom_file_upload").change(function() {
    $.post("someScript.php", function(data) {
        //Done!
    });
});
```

This binds an event handler function to the `change` event of the element, and uses the `post` method to fire an asynchronous request to "someScript.php".

There are various [jQuery AJAX methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) available to you. The right one to choose will depend on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Is there anyway of detecting if a DIV has changed, in the same way.

Comment: No, `div` elements do not have `change` events. Only `input`, `textarea` and `select` elements do. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well it's for a photo upload, I forgott the the input gets replaced by an SWF but there are DIV's that change when an upload is performed.

Comment: Depending on how the `div` changes, you may want to look into mutation events: https://www.adaptavist.com/display/jQuery/Mutation+Events